# Autofac and Quartz.Net Integration

Tags: autofac, quartz.net

Does anyone have any experience integrating **autofac** and **Quartz.Net**?  If so, where is it best to control lifetime management -- the IJobFactory, within the Execute of the IJob, or through event listeners?

---

Right now, I'm using a custom autofac `IJobFactory` to create the `IJob` instances, but I don't have an easy way to plug in to a `ILifetimeScope` in the IJobFactory to ensure any expensive resources that are injected in the IJob are cleaned up.  The job factory just creates an instance of a job and returns it.  Here are my current ideas (hopefully there are better ones...)

- It looks like most AutoFac integrations somehow wrap a `ILifetimeScope` around the unit of work they create.  The obvious brute force way seems to be to pass an `ILifetimeScope` into the `IJob` and have the `Execute` method create a child `ILifetimeScope` and instantiate any dependencies there.  This seems a little too close to a service locator pattern, which in turn seems to go against the spirit of autofac, but it might be the most obvious way to ensure proper handling of a scope.
- I could plug into some of the Quartz events to handle the different phases of the Job execution stack, and handle lifetime management there.  That would probably be a lot more work, but possibly worth it if it gets cleaner separation of concerns.
- Ensure that an IJob is a simple wrapper around an `IServiceComponent` type, which would do all the work, and request it as `Owned<T>`, or `Func<Owned<T>>`.  I like how this seems to vibe more with autofac, but I don't like that its not strictly enforceable for all implementors of IJob.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Without knowing too much about Quartz.Net and `IJob`s, I'll venture a suggestion still.

Consider the following Job wrapper:

```
public class JobWrapper<T>: IJob where T:IJob
{
    private Func<Owned<T>> _jobFactory;

    public JobWrapper(Func<Owned<T>> jobFactory)
    {
        _jobFactory = jobFactory;
    }


    void IJob.Execute()
    {
        using (var ownedJob = _jobFactory())
        {
            var theJob = ownedJob.Value;
            theJob.Execute();
        }
    }
}
```

Given the following registrations:

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(JobWrapper<>));
builder.RegisterType<SomeJob>();
```

A job factory could now resolve this wrapper:

```
var job = _container.Resolve<JobWrapper<SomeJob>>();
```

**Note:** a [lifetime scope](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/OwnedInstances) will be created as part of the `ownedJob` instance, which in this case is of type `Owned<SomeJob>`. Any dependencies required by `SomeJob` that is `InstancePerLifetimeScope` or `InstancePerDependency` will be created and destroyed along with the `Owned` instance.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to respond.  I like the idea in that it is a more explicit version of my third brainstorm in the original question.  What still bugs me is that I have no control over a lifetime scope.  Basically, I'd like to run each IJob in its own `LifetimeScope`, almost as the equivalent of a WCF service call.  The Quartz `IJobFactory` unfortunately is pretty much fire and forget from what I've been able to tell, so it may be that if I really want explicit scope boundaries, I'd have to dig into the Quartz listener system.

Comment: @dfaivre - I've corrected a bug in my code, I forgot the `ownedJob.Value` part. Perhaps my intentions are clearer now.

Comment: I did not know that Owned created a scope; very useful.  I think this is probably the most straight forward approach then without a deep dive into the Quartz stack.  I'll probably augment my `IJobFactory` to throw if job is not of type `JobWrapper<>` (just so I sleep a little better at night...).  Thanks again for the great insight.

Comment: So, a couple years later, I realized I misunderstood this answer, and that is an even better answer than I first though.  I was creating my jobs explicitly as a subclass of `JobWrapper<>`, which still tightly coupled me to Autofac, when really, I should have just been letting the `AutofacJobFactory` dynamically create the wrapper for me, allowing the underlying IJob to just declare its dependencies.  Some days...

Comment: @dfaivre - oh! Glad you found out! :-)

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at https://github.com/alphacloud/Autofac.Extras.Quartz. It also available as NuGet package https://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac.Extras.Quartz/

I know it a bit late:)